# normalize and efficient SQL Database desinging

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, database-design, relational-database

I have multiple users/customers (Let say N users)
and M number of articles.

bydeafult these M articles will be shown to each user. User can mark an article as "not interested". if he does so we will not show this article to him/her. but this article may be visible to other users who have not marked it as "not interested". right?

Now I'm having problem here. I dont want to create duplicate objects of article for different user. instead there should be some way/flag (`not_interested`) associated to each user so that we can filter out based on that. but I'm not sure how would I do that in SQL database.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Tables:

```
Article:
      title, description, etc..

User:
    username, email, phone, etc
```

should I create a middle table which will have foriegn key to article and user and a flag for not_interested? is there any better way?

Answer (score 1):

You need a many to many table, something like

```
user_article:
  article_id, user_id, not_interested
```

Comment: Or name the table something like `user_not_interested_in_article` and skip the `not_interested` column :-)

Comment: And use `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` to find the not-not_interested rows.